# Do not want to repeat myself

Tags: jquery

I have some links and when someone click on those links it will show up a popup which has some info.And then close it when user clicks on x.I have used jquery's show and hide to do this. Different links have different info so i have repeated myself and i want to know is there any way to not repeat myself.[This Link](http://jsbin.com/ovomaw/1/edit) will take you to jsbin where my code is and you understand what i am talking about.
Thank You.

Comment: Please include code with your question, don't just link to an external page containing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you give the div you are trying to show an id and the links you are clicking the same class and an href of the div id (this makes it more accessible too), you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GE6fX/1/

**html**

```
<a class="show" href="#zerotwo">link1</a>
<div id="zerotwo">
   <h1>Link heading <span>[close x]</span></h1>
   <p>blah</p>
</div>
<a class="show" href="#zerothree">link2</a>
<div id="zerothree">
   <h1>Link heading <span>[close x]</span></h1>
   <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    var showDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
    showDiv.show();
    showDiv.find('h1 span').click(function() {
        showDiv.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: same class means it will open the next popup too

Comment: that's where the id and href comes in - look at the fiddle it only opens the target div

Comment: when I click on link 1 popup opens then when I click link 2 again popup opens and that should not happen.

Comment: hahaha that's because I didn't realise you wanted the other popups to hide and I used the same text in both popups - they are actually diffent ones, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/GE6fX/4/

Comment: Yes I have tested it and its working fine thanks for the help.One more thing is when I click on the link if the hidden div is in the center of the page it drags me down any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class of the div you want to show from the link somehow, this is one way with `data-` attributes. if there is only one div on the page, it should be an id.

I've changed your links to have the same class 'show' (could be named better), the popup button i've given a class of `closepopup`, and your popups have a class of `popup` clicking either close one will hide all popups that are shown (this might not be the desired behavior)

Html

```
<body>
  <a class="show" data-popupid="zerotwo" href="#">link1</a>
  <a class="show" data-popupid="zerothree" href="#">link2</a>
    <div id="zerotwo" class="popup">
      <h1>Link heading <span class='closepopup'>[close x]</span></h1>
      <p>dhakshdakdhkhdahdlldhalksh</p>
    </div>
    <div id="zerothree" class="popup">
      <h1>Project completion report submission <span class='closepopup'>[close x]</span></h1>
       <p>dhakshdakdhkhdahdlldhalksh</p>
    </div>                    
</body>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show').click(function() {
    var popupClass = $(this).data('popupid');
    $('div#' + popupClass).show();
  });
  $('.closepopup').click(function() {
    $('div.popup').hide();
  });
});
```

You could make this neater by having one `div` on the page and control the content or the popup type from whichever link is clicked, then add the contents of the popup dynamically in JS.

Lots of solutions to this one, depending on your requirements.

Comment: I tested your code but the problem is same class means it will open the next popup too and that should not happen.

Comment: No, it only opens the div you want it to, it uses the id to open, the class to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up in multiple ways 
here I'm using only one popup div and is setting its content on each click instead.

http://jsbin.com/ovomaw/2/edit

or you can use some kind of templating library to add the html to your document for each popup(this will allow you to have multiple popups visible at once).

the right solution is hard to determine without knowing more about where your data is coming from etc